# How to practice mixed voice without sounding like I'm screaming?

Tags: technique, voice, practice, warm-up

I'm a **16-year-old high tenor** who recently found my **mixed voice** (YAY!!) about a week ago. When fully warmed up, I start mixing around Bb4 and go up to Ab5 and twice last week I hit an A5! Unfortunately, I can't do this every day since I don't get to practice much at home.

My mom hates hearing me practice since I'm "too loud".  She's always saying I'm screaming but I'm just trying to find that break and sing over it until my mix comes in.  I've never found my mix while she's home, but when my parents leave all of a sudden I can belt in the 5th octave like it's nothing.

To warm up, I usually warm up head voice, lower chest voice, head voice again (why not) and then upper chest voice.  After that, I try to practice mix, but it does take a few minutes of breaking before it finally comes in.  When it comes in, I sound great and feel free and all.  **Is there a way to warm up so that my mixed voice doesn't need 20 minutes to come in?** My parents only give me 30 mins of practice total b/c of homework.  All answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is possible for anyone here to answer this. You should never "sound like you are screaming" but of course that could just be your mum. You sound like you might well have a lot of natural vocal ability but also you might be developing habits that are not at all good. Look for a teacher who really knows what they are doing. You also need a place to practice where you don't have the feeling you are annoying people. Sorry I can't be more helpful than that.

Comment: Develop your ability to use mixed voice quickly--if you said you still need 20 minutes to start singing in mixed voice after 3 years of practice, I'd be really worried.

Comment: There seems to be some interesting stuff on YouTube, like _[Ep. 40 "The Mix Voice"- Voice Lessons To The World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYEsGuldIQY)_ by New York Vocal Coaching, but I do not know if it is any use to you. Perhaps it would help if you said how you learn to sing: are you just copying performers you like, or have you followed some singing lessons? And, in either case, say which ones, of course!

Comment: As far as the “screaming” is concerned, if you could learn to do it more quietly, it might not give you the sound you want, but it would probably improve your control and so be helpful anyway. And you could probably do it for longer without upsetting your parents!

Comment: Okay so I sang in my mix today and went up way into the 5th octave like I knew I could. I think what happened was I overused it.  I found my mix last Monday and then kept belting for a good 30 mins to an hour every day for the rest of the week.  In my lesson last night my teacher told me "Make sure not to sing those high notes all day every day" and I thought "Oh! Well, um..." lol  So I'm actually singing way up there, easily, I just learned not to overuse my voice and stuff.  I knew not too, but I kept getting excited and wanted to do it over and over again.  I'll make sure not to ever again.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a little counter intuitive, but singing quieter actually comes from good breath control. I recommend focusing on the link below, and being able to sing quieter will come naturally. [How to Breath While Singing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4ZZjEydSYM)

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually saying what the warm up consists of, or if it came from a voice teacher or not so it's tough to judge what's happening in the warmup. Also, you mentioned "belting" your mix voice. Mix voice and belting definetly don't go together.

Are you sure it's your mix voice you're using and not your head voice?
Mix voice can be used for either high or low notes and is a blending of chest and head voice that creates a lighter, easier sound.  Head voice is always used for high notes and can be strong (for example, Frankie Valie has a strong head voice - you can hear him switch back and forth in "Sherry", specifically when he goes from the "C" 1 octave over middle "C" down to middle "C" in an octave jump).

Best thing I can tell you is, if you're not working with a **good** voice coach, it's a good idea to do so, improper warm ups can mess your voice up, as can belting, and that's coming from a former belter!  :)